# jQuery Find hidden jems

Tags: jquery

How can I find number of none hidden rows, Here is the html

```
<div style="display:none;">
  <ul id="abc">
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li style="display:none;">List Item</li>
    <li class="hidden">List Item Hidden</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul { border: 1px solid blue; padding: 2px; margin: 2px;}
li { width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue;}
.hidden { display: none; }
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    alert($("#abc li:not(:hidden)").length);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/76NNp/27/

**EDIT**

The Code works as expected but what I want is

Finding Number of hidden List Items within a hidden Div...

**Note: it's a pop-up list, I am using some code to .hide() and .show() li but while list has display:none; I still want to find out how many items are visible, as if it's zero, i would hide the button that opens this pop-up list**

**EDIT------------------------------------------2**

FORGET EVERYTHING...

I want to find out number of not hidden list items that will become visible if Div they are in becomes visible.

Simple as milk now :-)

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach? Btw, you can shorten `:not(:hidden)` to `:visible`.

Comment: @haim770 if you check the fiddle, it will show you that I am not getting right number of li that are not hidden..

Comment: free to ask anything if any query

Comment: It's showing `2` in the alert, which is correct.

Comment: @CustomizedName, do you need number of elements which doesn't have class hidden?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry, I added link to wrong fiddle, updated it now http://jsfiddle.net/76NNp/27/

Comment: My poor 2 eyes only seeing 2 visible `li`. which is what your `alert` is showing.

Comment: Yes, guys, it was a typing mistake :-) sorry

Comment: @CustomizedName still showing right number... **0**

Comment: I think OP wants to know how many list items are visible when the parent is hidden

Comment: @CustomizedName your second fiddle is still correct as the parent element is hidden, therefore no child `li` elements are visible either.

Comment: May be like http://jsfiddle.net/76NNp/29/

Comment: @CustomizedName please, tell us what you are looking for (expecting) because all your jsfiddle work as expected

Comment: @billyonecan how on earth element will be visible if container is set to `display:none`

Comment: @billyonecan answer is simple, none are visibles

Comment: I know 0 are visible. I'm trying to explain that the OP would like to know how many list items are not explicitly hidden regardless of the state of the parent element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the elements and check if their `display` style is set to `none`. Something like this:

```
$(function () {
    var items = $("li").filter(function(){
        return $(this).css("display") != "none";
    });
    alert(items.length);
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2Tm5z/)

**NOTE**: This heavily depends on `display:none;` being the only factor that determines if an element is visible or not. If you use other methods such as `visibility:hidden;` then you will need to modify your filter to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this my friend:

```
    $(function () {
    $i = 0;
    $("ul > li").each(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('hidden') || $(this).css('display') != 'none')
            $i++;
    });
    alert($i);
});
```

Comment: Did you understand question?

Comment: I think you are on the wrong question...

Comment: sorry i can't see the parent display:none

Comment: And not getting exact question

Comment: @Jain: Please either edit you answer to provide a correct solution to match the question, or consider deleting the answer

Comment: yp i just edited it!!
Now i think is correct

Comment: Please review my answer now
thx 4 all